# What do i do if my players try to de limb something and its not a killing blow

Tags: optional-rules

Something that I've always thought about in d&d is what if my players attempt to cut the limb off something when it wouldn't kill the creature, such as a creature that only had a claw attack and they tried to take off its arms, would the creature still attack despite this?

Comment: Hello Logan, and welcome to RPG.stackexchange! Kindly take the [tour]. Which edition of D&D are you playing? It might have rules, optional or otherwise, for called shots, and those might apply here.

Comment: @iaminsensible Kindly refrain from answering in comments --- comments are meant for clarification and constructive critique, not answering. Thank you!

Comment: @iaminsensible: [Don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments), even as a speculative/generic answer. Feel free to leave a proper answer once OP has clarified their system/edition.